# ui-select: The value change at the same time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select, angular-ui-select

Have two ui-select like these in my page:

[image]

The problem is that when a change the value for the first select, the second one change too!

This is what i have in the html page:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="row">
        <ul ng-repeat="component in components_selected"
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                <strong><p>{{component.name}}</p></strong>
                <ui-select ng-model="service.frequencies" theme="bootstrap" 
                on-select="assignFrequency($item,$model)">
                    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a frequency">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
                        <ui-select-choices repeat="frequency in frequencies">
                            <small ng-bind-html="frequency.name"></small>
                    </ui-select-choices>
                </ui-select>
            </div>
        </ul>   
    </div>
</div>
```

{{component.name}}

 display me fine without repeat the info.

There is way to avoid that?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: because you have same `ng-model` to them

Comment: So, i can't avoid the problem?

Comment: what do you mean by can't avoid problem?

Comment: If there is a way that when i select one, the other not change?

Comment: yes, you should use different `ng-model` for both, `ng-model="service.frequencies1"` & `ng-model="service.frequencies2"`

Comment: that if i know the number of select, but dinamically? in a ng-repeat like i want to do?

Comment: then do use `ng-model="service.frequencies[$index]"`